# React Native state won't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, environment-variables

I'm working on my first game app.

What I want to do is passing GreenF to the Green component.

But the state won't change. I need GreenF to change whenever I need in the function play();

This is just the beginning of my code so nothing is full, but just for your understanding.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity, Button} from 'react-native';
    import Green from './components/Green.js'

     constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      greenF: false,
      score: 0,
      seq: [1,2,3,1,4],
      playerSeq: [],
      round: 1,
    }
  }

  play() {
    this.setState({ greenF: true });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Button 
        title='start' 
        color='black' 
        onPress={this.play}>

        </Button>
        <Green greenFlash={this.state.greenF}> </Green>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `play()` function too.

Comment: Submit the whole code. Talking about a function but do not share the function itself. How are we supposed to know your function ?

Comment: Just updated a code with more explanation of my question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncStorage`provided by react-native-community. It’s a persistent storage where you can set and get key-value storage.
Refer to this: https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

Either way you can also use redux for global state management.

Comment: Just updated a code with more explanation of my question, I am using state right now

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
Why are you looking for a way without using state?
State would be the "React Way" of handling this information especially since I assume you want to rerender your component after a value change.

But yes you can declare variables outside your render function or even outside of your component class.

When you are starting to learn react-native right now maybe have a look at functional components and react hooks (e.g. the useState hook for state) since is it the more modern way of writing react components.

When your state grows and needs to be shared between many different components in your tree you might want to look at react contexts or even a state managment library like redux.

**Edit**

I am adding a functional component version of your component as well to show how you could manage your state using hooks which to me is way easier since the state update is by far less complex. Note: Functionality is still only what your example is trying to do.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native'
import Green from './components/Green.js'

const App = props => {
    let score // user score
    let seq = [] //order of playing colors
    let playerSeq = [] //order of user pressing the colors
    let round // round number
    let ok //does the user pressed right
    let win
    let compTurn

    const [ greenF, setGreenF ] = useState(false) // [value, setter] = useState(initial)

    const play = () => {
        seq = [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 4 ] //just for test
        compTurn = true
        round = 1
        for (var i = 0; i < round; i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    setGreenF(true) // triggers rerender (after all state changes are done)
                    break
                case 2:
                    //tbchanged
                    break
                case 3:
                    //tbchanged
                    break
                case 4:
                    //tbchanged
                    break
            }
            compTurn = false
        }
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="start" color="black" onPress={play} />
            <Green greenFlash={greenF}> </Green>
        </View>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Just updated a code with more explanation of my question. I tried to understand the scope a little better and tried to avoid using state cause it was a little complicated, but here I chaged it and it's not working. The app is very small and simple

Comment: Hi, your changed code does have at least two minor mistakes:

First ```this.setState( greenF= true )``` should be ```this.setState({greenF: true })``` 

Second use ```<Green greenFlash={this.state.greenF}> </Green>``` to reference your current state and not the still present and unassigned ```let greenF;    ```

Comment: Hi, I also added a functional component version of your component so you can compare the two styles :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure what's not working, I tried copying your code and also changed mine as you mentioned and it's not working.